# save state of filters in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a code that is responsible for the data filter: the user make the criteria that are important to him and clicks "Apply". And sees a list based on the selected filters. But then these filters are reset, and if the user wants to make filters based on the previous ones, he has to select everything again. How to make that the state of the filters is saved and the user can continue filtering based on the previous request?

dialog_filter.dart

```
class FilterDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(Map<String, List<String>?>) onApplyFilters;

  const FilterDialog({Key? key, required this.onApplyFilters}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FilterDialog> createState() => _FilterDialogState();

}

class _FilterDialogState extends State<FilterDialog> {
  Map<String, List<String>?> filters = {};

  void _handleCheckFilter(bool checked, String key, String value) {

    final currentFilters = filters[key] ?? [];
    if(checked) {
      currentFilters.add(value);
    } else {
      currentFilters.remove(value);
    }
    filters[key] = currentFilters;

  }
```

page_main.dart

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  List<Phone> filteredPhones = phoneList;

  void _filter(Map<String, List<String>?> filters) {
    setState(() {
      filteredPhones = phoneList;
      filters.forEach((key, value) {
        if((value ?? []).isNotEmpty) {
          filteredPhones = filteredPhones.where((phone) {
            switch(key) {}
          }).toList();
        }
      });
    });
  }
class Filter {
    String name;
    bool Function(Phone) filterFn;

    Filter({required this.name, required this.filterFn});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use state management libraries like `provider, bloc, mobx , riverpod` etc.

So if you still want use `stateful widget` then you have to maintain a list of selected filters at parent level pass to your dialog and return back when user selects anything. This will be very complex and bug prone to do with only stateful widget.

If don't want use any libraries then you can use `ValueNotifier` or `InheritedWidget`. But I would suggest state management library is more easier. Start with [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) it's easiest.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I study Flutter two weeks. Can you help me write the code with library provider based on my code?